# Base64 encoded string to downloadable file in AngularJS and Asp.net MVC as business Tier

Tags: angularjs, download, base64

```
.controller('exportContactsCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', 'uploadServices', '$window', function ($scope, $interval, uploadServices, $window) {
$scope.downloadExpContacts = function () {
    console.log('This is Export Contacts page');
    var exportData = {};
    uploadServices.downloadFile().then(function (response) {
        exportData = response.data;
        if (exportData.csvFile != undefined) {
            $window.open("data:application/x-compressed;base64," + encodeURIComponent(exportData.csvFile));
        }
    });
```

I am trying to provide a downloadable zip file from  base64 encoded string.

I am reading the string by using uploadService and getting it from an backend API, which will give me the base64 string

I am using above code on click on button to download the file ,

I am getting the download as corrupt zip , may i know what i am missing